# Reading membership section from web.config

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, membership, web-config

I have created a custom MembershipProvider class, so far so good, however, I am not sure how to read the configuration settings from the web.config file.

I tried to search from Google and Stackoverflow, seems like someone also experiencing my 
problem and asked, but no answer has been given.

It should be a simple thing, but I am very new in web development, so reading settings from web.config seems away too technical to me.

Here is my settings:

```
 <membership defaultProvider="CustomMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="CustomMembershipProvider"
         type="Test.Models.CustomMembershipProvider,Test"
         passwordFormat="Hashed"
         connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
         minRequiredPasswordLength="8"
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
         enablePasswordReset="false"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
         applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

I would like to read the `minRequiredPasswordLength` setting, please assist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As this is set as your default provider it should be enough to:

```
int i = Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength;
```

And that would return an int specifying the minimum required password length.

Comment: Sorry to add to this, but how about the `PasswordFormat` section?

Answer (score 21):

here is the solution in code :

```
        MembershipSection membershipSection = (MembershipSection)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/membership");
        string defaultProvider = membershipSection.DefaultProvider;
        ProviderSettings providerSettings = membershipSection.Providers[defaultProvider];
        string connectionStringName = providerSettings.Parameters["connectionStringName"];
        string connectionUsername = providerSettings.Parameters["connectionUsername"];
        string connectionPassword = providerSettings.Parameters["connectionPassword"];
        string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, I was looking for a way to load the default provider from config.

Answer (score 2):

If you have overridden the `System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider` in your own class you can get the web.config membership settings as Robban suggests, just by calling the `System.Web.Security.Membership` methods. However, these calls will be directed to your membership provider class, so you will need to provide some implementation.

Supposing you have overridden the `MembershipProvider` class and added a section in the config file, as in the original question above. A call to int `i = Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength` will be directed to YOUR implementation. This might look like this:

```
   public override int MinRequiredPasswordLength
    {
        get { return _minRequiredPasswordLength; }
    }
```

MSDN gives a complete example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75.aspx). The example shows you how to read the config file to set the local properties like `_minRequiredPasswordLength`.