# ASPNetAuthentication -- where to find the minRequiredPasswordLength

Tags: c#, web-config, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, asp.net-authentication

Having a bit of trouble getting this right...
The main objective is to have user configurable password strengths and here's where I get stuck:
There's a setting in some config file somewhere that specifies the minimum password length to be seven and I can't for the life of me find the blasted thing, I've checked the the app.config for the specific provider implementation, the web.config for the solution ( where the parameter is mentioned but set to 1), and I've even checked the .config files for anything even touching this but there's nothing.  Kinda frustrating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the `minRequiredPasswordLength` is configured in your Membership provider section. Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12702649/114029) to see an example where it's set to 6.

Given that, you should access this value using the following property on the `Membership` type:

```
var minPassLength = System.Web.Security.Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength;
```

If it doesn't work maybe you have a custom provider implementation that overrides the property value set in `Web.config` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9990435/114029) for an example. In this case I'd suggest you do a search in your entire solution to find the string `minRequiredPasswordLength` and see from where this value is coming. If the custom provider comes from a third party DLL, you must have access to the library code to change that value.